# How to dynamic loading when compiling artisan console?

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, compilation

This is my code.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use App\Events\RedisEvent;

class RedisSubscribe extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'redis:subscribe';

    protected $description = 'Subscribe redis channel for socket communication';

    protected $redisSubClient;

    protected $redisCacheClient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->redisSubClient = Redis::connection('redis_socket_sub');
        $this->redisCacheClient = Redis::connection('redis_cache');
    }

    public function handle()
    {   

        $this->redisSubClient->subscribe(['fromClient'], function($data) {
                    if($this->redisCacheClient->get(config('lunachat.yellow_id').'_socket_mode') == 1) {

                        $par = [
                            '
                            '
                            '
                            '
                            '
                        ];
                        event(new RedisEvent($par));
                    }
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is eventlistener

```
class RedisEventListener
{

    public $par;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(RedisEvent $event)
    {
        $this->par = $event->par;
        $api = new Api();
        if ($api->find($this->par['id'])) {
            $api->apiCallWrite($this->par);
        }   
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I run this program, all of the code associated with the event will load and run together.

Therefore, if I modify the related code, I must restart the program again.

However, this is not the case with my service conditions.

For this reason, this program only compiles and executes code up to execute the event, and the subsequent logic wants to be compiled and executed dynamically.

I would like to know if this is possible in Laravel.